# AnguarJS + node.js (web-server.js) remove hashtag from url and support it by server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-routing

As far as i understand in order to remove the hashtag from angularJS i need to add the following code:

```
config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}).
```

after added this code, i get 404 from my simple server (web-server.js) which is the same simple server provided with angular tuotorial.

From the stackoverflow i found 2 links that helped me to understand that i need to add routing to my server in order to support this operation.

[AngularJs Routing without hashtag in link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335251/angularjs-routing-without-hashtag-in-link)

[routing and clean path (no hashtag) not working in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727602/routing-and-clean-path-no-hashtag-not-working-in-angularjs)

well i didn't understand how to add web-server.js the routing i needed

my link was previously was: /app/index.html/#cars
and now he is /app/index.html/car

how should i changed web-server.js in order to fit my new routing needs?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simlpiest and the fastest way to set up node server with routing is to use [Express](http://expressjs.com/) framework.

With Express very simple skeleton of your webapp would look like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/app');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');       //EJS template engine (no HTML for now)
    app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  //specify path to your static files
});

//"car", "bus", and "van" are the pages of your app
app.get('/:page(|car|bus|van)', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        page: req.params.page     //pass page to the view (just in case)
    });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

Then you will have to create `/app/index.ejs` file which is in fact the html file with some additioal features.

Thus, when you navigate in your browser to `/car`, `/bus`, or `/van` you will see the content of `index.ejs` file.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

I've just corrected `/:page(|car|bus|van)` part. Please try the last version

**Edit 2**

Oh, I forgot to say, you have to `npm install ejs` from command line to start using EJS templates

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, i added the pages and ran the script, seems that the server is up but i always get Cannot GET /app/index.html as a response, what can i do?

Comment: @LiadLivnat you should not navigate to `/app/index.html`. You should navigate to `/`, `/car`, etc. In my example in `app.get` method I specified to serve app/index.ejs file for `/car`, `/bus`, and `/van` requests. I also edited my post (now it works good with `/` request)

Comment: thanks, i get the following error : "Error: Cannot find module 'ejs' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)"

Comment: i will install npm install ejs

Comment: now i get the index.ejs but i don't get the angular page i was looking for

Comment: Try to open your browser's Network tab and reload a page. Do you see angular.js script successfully loaded?

Comment: @LiadLivnat I think something wrong in this line `app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`. What is the directory of your js and css files?

Comment: [Here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) you can read more about `static` middleware

Comment: Don't have any call on network tab, i don't have any folder name public, my js /css are at on folders at the same path as the index pages

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47124/discussion-between-zub-and-liad-livnat)